# Date field not showing in Esri Feature services?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5, feature-service

I published a feature service with one field as a date.

When I consumed the web service and I open it up in a web map, in the configure attributes, the date field is not showing up.

I have handled it before but cannot recollect how. Perhaps it's done at the geodatabase level?

Comment: What does the field look like in your browser when you open the rest endpoint URL?

Comment: I am already in 10.5. Sorry I put it in 10.1. It comes only as date, the time part doesn't show up

Comment: As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It explains how you can [edit] the question to improve it. Sometimes a date without time is just a string, sometimes it's a format issue. You'll need to tell us which. Screenshots and/or XML or JSON metadata would not be inappropriate.